# Trigger.io or Steriods.js for pushing code to native app without compiling?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, trigger.io

I'm researching solutions for deploying updates without compiling code into an app that requires review/approval by App Store. [Trigger.io's Reload](https://trigger.io/reload/) and [Steriods.js](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) are two potential options. What are your experiences in using either one for building native apps using web technologies (html5, css3, javascript)?

My current frontend stack is angular.js, ionic framework, and phonegap. I'm having issues with native app build sometime failing using remote build (on adobe's build.phonegap.com) and I was thinking of switching to another system for building.

Answer (score 2):

I come from the same exact front end experience and trigger was a breeze to get up and running. Now that I have been using it within my company in production for about half a year, I have continued to find it better than phone gap. There are definetly times where trigger gives weird errors or you have to restart the toolkit (local served config page).

Overall I suggest it a lot, but it can get costly in the long run unless you have your company paying for it. I would try out ionic-cordova. The builder from ionic uses Cordova and makes things pretty simple. It was easier to get my boss on the train of using trigger though instead  of an open sourced platform (he wanted to be able to call support). Speaking of which, their support was pretty good too. It was personal, but the guys seem pretty busy with things and didn't seem to be able to solve problems very quickly. Most times we solved/ avoided the error before they got back to us by email (but for some pretty specific stuff).
Overall I have really loved trigger and would suggest it to anyone looking for something different than phonegap. The documentation and amount of good plugins for trigger makes most things pretty straight forward.
Hope this helps somewhat.